# Why aren't users notified when their questions are closed?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, notifications

On a few occasions, I've noticed that I haven't gotten any kind of notification when my own questions was closed. For example, when [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150203/is-it-possible-to-convert-requirejs-modules-to-commonjs) was closed as "off-topic", I didn't see any kind of notification in the Stack Exchange navigation bar, and I only noticed the change after I did a Google search for the question, and realized that it had been closed earlier.

I think users should be notified when their questions are closed so that they will at least be given a chance to improve their questions. Since no notification is given for question closures, some question closures continue to unnoticed until months have passed. By then, the questions may either be too old to migrate to the correct site, or may [run  the risk of automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year), depending on the specific closing reason.

I think notifications for closed questions should be implemented for all of the above reasons. The original poster of a question ought to be given a chance to improve and reopen their question, before it's too late for them to make any changes.

Comment: How important was it for you to get an answer to  your question if you let months pass before checking up on it?

Comment: Especially now that there is a five day "on hold" status.

Comment: Since you're going to say that's not the point, why should your particular question (and its answers) be immortalized for all time?  Not all material is worthy of such preservation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The particular question that I asked is mostly irrelevant. This feature request doesn't only apply to that particular question: it applies to all questions that are potentially useful and have some chance of being improved by their askers.

Comment: This question has been c̶l̶o̶s̶e̶d̶  marked as a duplicate of another question.  See the duplicate link displayed in the banner above the question.

Answer (score 2):

Questions that run the risk of automatic deletion do not deserve preservation.  If nobody has shown enough interest in a question to answer it before a whole year is passed, then there's not enough of a value proposition to keep it around.

Accordingly, no notification should be necessary for such a question.  Let it pass quietly into the night.

Comment: I think those questions would deserve preservation if substantial improvements were made to them. If users were notified when these questions were closed, then they could improve those questions so that they would actually become relevant and useful.

Comment: The lack of answers after several days is ample evidence that the question needs to be improved.

Comment: I'm not sure which question you're referring to.

Comment: Any question that's been around for more than, say, five days (the "on hold period") without an upvote or answer posted to it.

Comment: Also, I'm suggesting that users should be notified when any of their questions were closed (not only one-year old questions). This would at least allow them to improve their questions before it's too late for them to do anything.